# innerHTML assigned to a variable cannot be updated live?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm trying to connect a div's text with a variable that changes value according to different buttons onclicks(with plain js), but cant figure out how to update the inner.HTML in a live manner,it just takes whatever value is on page load.
What am i doing wrong ?
Js student here.

```js
var counter1=0;
var counter2=0;
var counter3=0;

var countertotal=counter1+counter2+counter3;
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML= "Total" + "&nbsp" + parseInt(countertotal);

function count1() {
document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML =parseInt(counter1);
counter1++;
}
function count2() {
document.getElementById("button2").innerHTML =parseInt(counter2);
counter2++;
}
function count3() {
document.getElementById("button3").innerHTML =parseInt(counter3);
counter3++;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id='text' style="font-size:50px"></div>
<button style= "width:400px; height:150px; font-size:100px;
 display:block" id="button1" onclick="count1()"></button>

<button style="width:400px;height:150px; font-size:100px;
 display:block" id="button2" onclick="count2()"></button>

<button style="width:400px;height:150px;font-size:100px;display:block" id="button3" onclick="count3()"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update the counter total after clicking on each button and then update the counter total innerHTML. You only update the counter on a single button instance.

For example on function count1

```
function count1() {
   document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML =parseInt(counter1);
   counter1++;
   countertotal++;
   document.getElementById("text").innerHTML =  "Total" + "&nbsp" + 
   parseInt(countertotal);
}
```

Also the countertotal value doesn't update automatically because code is run from top to bottom and you pass values by value. For more info on this topic you can read here: [value vs reference](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20all%20function%20arguments,arguments%20inside%20of%20the%20function.&text=If%20function%20arguments%20are%20passed,be%20reflected%20outside%20the%20function.)